# How to use where clause to match the combination of multiple columns in one go without using AND or OR clauses

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I wanted to match the combination of multiple columns as that from another table or the same table itself.

For example, see table1 and table2.

[image]

[image]

So, I want the output like below.

[image]

So far, I have been using `AND` clause to achieve this like below:

```
select * from table1
where col1 in (select col4 from table2) 
and col2 in (select col5 from table2)
and col3 in (select col6 from table2)
```

But it is not giving me the exact output. So, I am looking for such a query which can work for my scenario. **Any help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question and SQL query for the same is given below.

```
select * from table1
where (col1,col2,col3) in (select col4,col5,col6 from table2);
```

But still, if anybody has any better solution then it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `INTERSECT` set operator which is used to return the results of multiple (two or more) SELECT statements for those each column values should be equal for the respective order of columns.

So, consider using as below :

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM table2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eed06b8520f7814e219b980e20b60162)</kbd>